# Pick the missing records with latest dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables with only 3 common fields.
I wrote the below query to pick up the missing data with Latest date in table 1.

```
Employee Category Date_Field   First_Name Last_Name Status   Result
100      Type1    30/08/2010   A          B          Present  Good
200      Type1    1/09/2010    C          D          Hello    Alt
100      Type3    30/09/2010   A          B 
100      Type1    30/09/2012   A          B 


Employee Category Date_Field   
100      Type1     03/11/2016 
100      Type3     30/09/2010 
100      Type4     11/10/2010
200      Type3     12/12/1989
```

My Query is

```
with x1 as (SELECT Employee,Category,Date_Field,First_Name,Last_Name,Status,Result,' ' as Somefield from table 1
where not exists 

(select 1 from table2
where table1.employee=table2.employee and table1.category = table2.Category
and table1.Date_Field = table2.Date_Field)),

x2 as (select Employee,Category,Max(Date_Field) as DateField from x1 group by Employee)

select x1.Employee,x1.Category,x1.Date_Field,x1.First_Name,x1.Last_Name,x1.Status,x1.Result,x1.Somefield from x1,x2
where x1.Employee = x2.Employee and x1.Date_Field=x2.DateField and x1.Category=x2.Category
order by x1.Employee;
```

The Current Ouptput i get is

```
Employee Category Date_Field  First_Name Last_Name Status Result
100     Type1     30/09/2012  A           B 
200     Type1     1/09/2010   C           D        Hello Alt
```

Can i get this query modified so that If there ia record for the same employee with latest date and category in table 2, my output should not have that record.

So the expected Output is

```
Employee Category Date_Field First_Name Last_Name Status Result
200      Type1    1/09/2010  C          D         Hello  Alt
```

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you can ignore the datefield for the `NOT EXISTS` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 'x' FROM TABLE2 T2
  WHERE T1.EMPLOYEE = T2.EMPLOYEE
   AND T1.CATEGORY = T2.CATEGORY
   AND T2.DATEFIELD >= T1.DATEFIELD
)
```

Comment: Maheshwaran if I'm removing the date field its going to return all the missing data from table 1 which are not in which i don't require. I need to check whether the Latest record for an employee per category is from table 1, if yes i need to populate it or else ignore

Comment: The Updated SQL should help it.

Comment: @AnnieJeba it should be working. I don't see a problem with it.